# Update csr_matrix with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` object with size is `full_sites_sparse.shape` `(336358, 48371)`. Also I have dataframe which size is `union_df[hour].shape` `(336358, 17)`. How could I union this two objects that after that size of `full_sites_sparse.shape` will be `(336358, 48388)`?

Comment: Do you have enough memory to make `arr = full_sites_sparse.A`, the full dense array?  If so you could do a `np.hstack`.  But if you need to keep things sparse. use `sparse.hstack` to join `full_sites_sparse` and a sparse matrix made from the `union_df.values`.

Comment: @hpaulj You mean this? `np.hstack((full_sites_sparse.A, union_df[hour].values))`